# How can I set seo title tags with Rails Devise on the Sign In and Sign Up pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Where in rails + devise can I set a var in the controller like so:

```
@content_for_title = 'Sign In'

@content_for_title = 'Sign Up'
```

Which would then be set in my layout file:

```
<title><%= page_title %></title>
```

Is there a way to take control of:

```
Devise::SessionsController#new controller to just set that var?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Other than just adding a

```
     <title>Mysite | Mysite is so great and here is where you sign in!</title>
```

In the view, I believe you can partially override the sessions controller to add a @title instance:

```
     SessionsTitlesController::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController 

     def new
        @title = "Mysite is so great and here is where you sign in!"
     end

     end
```

Then change your routes:

```
     devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "sessionstitles" }
```

Just in case you haven't created Devise views yet, you execute this to generate views:

```
     rails generate devise:views
```

Also, to get the above code to work you'll need to have a title helper in your application_controller along this sort of lines:

```
     def title
      base_title = "My site"
        return base_title if @title.nil?
        return "#{@title} | #{base_title}
     end
```